# How to disable all the physical buttons present on a tablet device

Tags: android

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:visible="false"/>


</menu>
```

I have tried doing this, But only the setting button gets invisible. I want to disable all the buttons present on my tab.

I have even tried doing ths

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
   }
```

But no results obtained.

Comment: Also try `setHomeButtonEnabled(false)`

Comment: Can't you put `android:visibility="invisible"` to all the buttons in the XML or do it programatically?

Comment: setHomeButtonEnabled(false) is not working.. and for visibility, i dont have any buttons, i just want to disable the hardware buttons present, i.e. the home button, back button, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hide elements in `ActionBar`:

If you want to disable the Up-Button you should to this:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

If you don't want a `OptionsMenu` than delete your `onCreateOptionsMenu` Method.

**UPDATE 2013 11 22:**

Hide System Navigation:

```
    View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    rootView.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION );
```

But please read the API of this FLAG:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

Comment: it does work on title bar but i want to disable my "home" and "back" buttons too.

Comment: ok, this wasn't clear for me. I thought you talked about the ActionBar. Don't know if this is possible...did you see soemthing like this before in another app?

Comment: @Meghs: I know it's late for an answer. But I found something that could be the answer to your question...see the update in my answer.